# How to save NSManagedObject in userdefaults

Tags: iphone

Hi all,

How can I save an `NSManagedObject` in `userDefault`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `ObjectID`, transform into `NSURL` using the `URIRepresentation`, and then archive it in a `NSData` using the `NSKeyedArchiver`. Now you can save it in the userdefaults.